# Overriding "items" in Android's style.

Tags: android, coding-style, overriding

I have an Android library with themes, attributes, styles, colors and, of course, code.

For things like separator's height, colors of items etc.. i have the ability to override dimensions using dimensions.xml and color using colors.xml (leaving the layouts, theme and style alone).

However, if i have a ListView which uses Android's list_selector_background and i also have another activity which uses this selector for a press-able TextView, besides overriding it in code, I can't find a way to do it though of using the ?style:attrib syntax but i can't see how it helps

The simple and fastest solution i currently have is create a style:

```
<style name="ResultsListViewStyle" >
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
</style>
```

and then copy paste the above piece of xml to my actual project style.xml and change the selector there. This is not so bad however i do need to do this for every item using this selector...

Comment: is it possible to define in attrs.xml something like: <attr name="my_selector" format="drawable"/> outside of <declare-stylale> clause and then use it in my style like so:
>@attr:/my_selector"
the value itself i'll define and override in the theme.xml, i saw attrs.xml of the android sdk does that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since no one picked the glove eventually I found the solution, indeed as an attribute.
The solution:

1. In your *attrs.xml* create an entry for the value you need, for drawbale like selector for example use:   `<attr name="ListResultSelector" format="reference" />`
2. In your *theme.xml* define your theme, if that attribute is your only one and you want Android normal theme as your theme you can use:

   ```
   <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
     <item name="ListResultSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. If you want to override in a specific application you can simple inherit 'theme' (`<style name="Theme.newTheme">`) and change that specific property there.
4. In  your style instead of defining a drawable you can define: `<....android:background="?attrib:ListResultSelector" ../>`
5. Apply the theme either to your application or to the relevant activity

In this way I don't need to override an entire style, only special properties like drawables, type faces etc... inside it. So if I ever need to change something in the original style and I want it to effect both the old and the new applications I don't need to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

In correction to @codeScriber's answer:

Resources defined in themes can be referenced in layouts via `?attr/ListResultSelector` or just `?ListResultSelector`.

Also refer to the docs concerning this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes